# Kensai PrC "Multiclass" Clause

Tags: dnd-3.5e, multi-classing, prestige-class

The DnD 3.5e Kensai PrC contains this clause:

> **Multiclass Note:** A samurai, paladin, or monk who becomes a kensai may continue advancing in his original class.

Does this mean that they continue advancing *while* taking Kensai levels? That seems to be the only logical conclusion -- much like the [Evangelist PrC](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/evangelist/) in PF, which has

> **Aligned Class (Ex)**
>   Evangelists come from many different backgrounds, and they show an unusual range of diversity. At 2nd level, the evangelist must choose a class she belonged to before adding the prestige class to be her aligned class. She gains all the class features for this class, essentially adding every evangelist level beyond 1st to her aligned class to determine what class features she gains. She still retains the Hit Dice, base attack bonus, saving throw bonuses, and skill ranks of the prestige class, but gains all other class features of her aligned class as well as those of the evangelist prestige class.

Kensai does not give anything that is listed as stacking, so most other options don't seem to apply. If this is a full-progression PrC...that is awesome :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This allows you to take levels in these classes after taking some levels in the Kensai PrC. You do not gain the features from both in a single level.

This is an exception to the general rule that prevents these classes from taking further levels when they decide to multiclass.

Take a look at the [paladin](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/paladin.htm) for example:

> Like a member of any other class, a paladin may be a multiclass character, but multiclass paladins face a special restriction. **A paladin who gains a level in any class other than paladin may never again raise her paladin level**, though she retains all her paladin abilities. (emphasis mine)

So, while taking a level in another class usually prevents any further paladin levels from being obtained, this is not the case with the Kensai.